# How to set the ordering of a taxonomy term's listing page

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

When you click on a tag term (or any other taxonomy term), a page is displayed listing the nodes tagged with that term. How can the nodes be displayed alphabetically?

The only module that looks like it could yield results is this one: http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display

But as of yet, can't get this to work as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the Views module, enable the Taxonomy view. You can customise the content of the tag results page by adding/ordering fields, just as you would any other view.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use the [Node Order](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeorder) module:

> The nodeorder module gives users an easy way to order nodes within
>   their taxonomy terms.

A PHP way is also described in the question: [alphabetize the taxonomy term page without views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56898/alphabetize-the-taxonomy-term-page-without-views)